# Python scientific: interrupt differential equation solving with a condition

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am currently solving a system of differential equation under python using [odeint](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) to simulate charged particles in a field (the source comes from this [package](http://packages.python.org/pytrap/)):

```
time = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000)

def sm(x, t): 
    return np.array([x[1], eta*Ez0(x[0])])

traj = odeint(sm,[0,1.], time)
```

It works fine but I would like to stop the calculation as soon as x[0] < 0. For the moment I just block the evolution of the sytem:

```
def sm1(x, t): 
    if x[0] < 0:
        return np.array([0, 0]) 
    else:
        return np.array([x[1], eta*Ez0(x[0])])

traj = odeint(sm1,[0,1.],time)
```

but I gess there are better solutions. I've found [this](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2009-January/019522.html) but is seems to me that it fixes the number of steps, which is regrettable.
Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Your solution seems pretty reasonable to me. What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: you get a warning: lsoda--  at current t (=r1), mxstep (=i1) steps taken on this call before reaching tout     
      In above message,  I1 =       500
      In above message,  R1 =  0.4223349048304E+00
Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).
Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write a custom extension of the odeint function, you could have your function raise a particular exception when it's finished. Doing it in Python might make it substantially slower, but I think you write the same thing in C or Cython. Note that I haven't tested the following.

```
class ThatsEnoughOfThat(Exception):
    pass

def custom_odeint(func, y0, t): # + whatever parameters you need
    for timestep in t:
        try:
            # Do stuff. Call odeint/other scipy functions?
        except ThatsEnoughOfThat:
            break
    return completedstuff

def sm2(x, t):
    if x[0] < 0:
       raise ThatsEnoughOfThat
    return np.array([x[1], eta*Ez0(x[0])])
```